# Rails associations within same model depending on attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, scope, associations

I am building a rails app with devise and cancancan and I am trying to create associations within the same model. I have a User model, a role model and an appointments model. The user can have the role of Doctor or Patient. I want to create an association so a Patient can create appointments with the Doctor. I managed to create the associations but I do not know how to make the patient only create appointments with a doctor and only in that way.
My models are like this:

**User model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  belongs_to :role, optional: true
  validates :name, :DOB, presence: true
  has_many :doctor_user_appointments, class_name: 'Appointment', foreign_key: 'doctor_user_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :patient_user_appointments, class_name: 'Appointment', foreign_key: 'patient_user_id', dependent: :destroy
  before_save :assign_role
  scope :doctor_user, -> {where("role_id = ?", 1)
  scope :patient_user, -> {where("role_id = ?", 2)
  def admin?
    role.name == 'Admin'
  end

  def doctor?
    role.name == 'Doctor'
  end
  
  def patient?
    role.name == 'Patient'
  end
  
  def assign_role
    self.role = Role.find_by name: 'Patient' if role.nil?
  end
end
```

**Role model**

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
end
```

**Appointment model**

```
class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :doctor_user, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :patient_user, class_name: 'User'
end
```

With these models, I can create appointments between doctor_user and patient_user, both users, but the associations do not distinguish who has the role "doctor" and who has the role "patient". I have tried with scopes but it is not working.
What I basically want is that doctor_user could only be a user with role "doctor" or user with role_id=1 and a patient_user only could be  a user with role_id=2 or role "patient"

Any help would be welcome since I am quite stuck
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Simply updating with the following lines to your **Appointment** controller will do the job:

```
belongs_to :doctor_user, -> { doctor_user }, class_name: 'User'
belongs_to :patient_user, -> { patient_user }, class_name: 'User'
```

Comment: Thanks. This is not working, actually, I cannot create appointments after adding these lines. I guess I need to add something else to my models

Comment: What error appointment is giving on creation? Have you tried simply querying as `Appointment.first.doctor_user` ? Because, what i am doing here is referencing the association with scope defined in user model which is getting the users with role doctor and patient respectively.

Comment: Your solution may work but it is not what I was looking for, the issue was to only make doctor_user to users with the role of doctor. With your solution, a patient could be also a doctor at an appointment, which is not what I needed

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by adding these lines to the Appointment model

```
belongs_to :doctor_user, -> {where("role_id = ?", 1)}, class_name: 'User'
belongs_to :patient_user, -> {where("role_id = ?", 2)}, class_name: 'User'
```

Comment: `where(role_id: 1)` is the preferred way